# Set a Rails form hidden field from enum model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, enums, hidden-field

I have multiple social networks available in my model:

```
class Social < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum kind: [ :twitter, :google_plus, :facebook, :linked_in, :skype, :yahoo ]
  belongs_to :sociable, polymorphic: true
  validates_presence_of :kind
  validates_presence_of :username
end
```

I want to use something like this in my view.

```
<%= f.fields_for :socials do |a| %>
  <%= a.select  :kind, Social.kinds.keys, selected: :skype %><br />
  Skype ID: <%= a.text_field :username %>
<% end %>
```

But I want to enforce the kind to be skype and not be user modifiable.  So I'm trying to switch it to a `hidden_field` tag.  But I'm not having any luck with it.

So the user should only see the label "Skype ID" with a username input box where they don't see the `kind` selected in the hidden field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and set a hidden field like so, and it should work for `enum`

```
<%= a.hidden_field :kind, {value: 'skype'} %>
```

You don't really need it to be a select tag if the user cannot select, or even see the option.